# Карты Яндекс и React

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api

Пробую использовать [react-yandex-maps](https://github.com/gribnoysup/react-yandex-maps). Карта рисуется в левом углу. Не могу понять, как ее на весь экран сделать?

Comment: Надо писать разработчкику https://github.com/gribnoysup/react-yandex-maps

Answer (score 1):

Может кому пригодится:

```
<Map state={mapState} width={"100%"} height={"100%"}
```

Вопрос закрыт!